# python, pygsheets question - how to gain the color of each cell in a column, fast?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, pygsheets

i have this code, that checks color of each cell in a google sheets worksheet.
that would be ok, but for 1200 rows, it takes 400 seconds to do so, so i wanted to ask if someone know of a better way to check color of a each cell in a column(i couldnt find how to check only 1 column, and not the whole sheet), and put it in a list?
can i use get_all_values() for only 1 column?

```
import pygsheets
cells = cyber_worksheet.get_all_values(returnas='cell',include_tailing_empty=False, include_tailing_empty_rows=False)
color_code = []
for r in cells:
    for c in r:
        color_code.append(c.color)
return color_code
```

this worked, but very very slowly.... i was wondering if there was

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from only one column instead of all cells.
- You want to achieve this using pygsheets.

In this case, how about using `get_col` instead of `get_all_values`? When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
cells = cyber_worksheet.get_all_values(returnas='cell',include_tailing_empty=False, include_tailing_empty_rows=False)
color_code = []
for r in cells:
    for c in r:
        color_code.append(c.color)
```

#### To:

```
cells = cyber_worksheet.get_col(1, returnas="cell", include_tailing_empty=False)
color_code = []
for r in cells:
    color_code.append(r.color)
```

- In this case, the values are retrieved from column "A". When you want to retrieve the values from the column "B", please modify `cyber_worksheet.get_col(1, returnas="cell", include_tailing_empty=False)` to `cyber_worksheet.get_col(2, returnas="cell", include_tailing_empty=False)`.
- In this case, it seems that the value of `cells` is a one-dimensional array, and each element is each row.

#### Note:

- If you use `get_all_values`, how about the following modification?

  ```
    col = 1  # Column "A"
    cells = cyber_worksheet.get_all_values(returnas="cell", include_tailing_empty=False, include_tailing_empty_rows=False)
    color_code = []
    for r in cells:
        color_code.append(r[col - 1].color)
  ```

#### Reference:

- [get_col(col, returnas='matrix', include_tailing_empty=True, **kwargs)](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/worksheet.html?highlight=get_all_values#pygsheets.Worksheet.get_col)